# Creation of Navigation mesh object dynamically

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine

I have a grid and at run time my application determines certain path on the grid. As shown in the image. When the path is calculated, I have list of center of all the cells, for example starting from 'A' till 'B' shown in the image.

Now, my question is, if there is a way I can dynamically create a navigation mesh from the list of centers, starting from A to B. By dynamic I mean, passing the list of centers, can I create a navigation object in python ?
Please help me with some idea or code snippets, thanks in advance !

[image: highlighted path cells]

Comment: (Supposing you are working in the bge): If you dont care about it beaing a single object, you can simply create the strucure from the little squares in an iterative fashion (moving an empty around and activating Add Mesh-actuators (I believe it is called something like "Mesh edit", I have to admit I don't know the exact name).  However, I don't think there is a meaningful way to create a real mesh inside the BGE. I hope I am wrong on the last one. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I am sorry, I dont quite get that. For example, I have a python-dict which has the centers on the selected cells from the grid. Now is there a way I can create a new navigation mesh object , may be by using Blender python API or something,  somehow from the cells I have in the dict.

Comment: I don't see a meaningful way to do it with bpy.directly. Instead, by using the logic-bricks and python together, you could use an actuator through Python. See here: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_62_release/bge.logic.html

Comment: Also, you could maybe have all the grid's objects around but in a hidden + ghost state. Then you could try to make them visible and disable the ghost-state by iterating through them. In any case, you must be able to convert the center's co-ordinates to the position in the grid.

Comment: Thank you user277143, but still its not clear. I have this grid, as shown in the image. And I have an object which is allowed to move on the grid. For that I need to determine a path, which in this case is a sequence of cells from the grid. To make the object move, I have some python set-up. As pointed out in the earlier comment, using the Logic-Bricks, I have an Steering Actuator object (with path following behavior). For now, the navigation mesh for this steering actuator is hardcoded.

Comment: But needless to say, other than the shown path (A to B) in the image, the I will have different path structure and so I need to reassign my steering actuator with newly formed navigation mesh.  Hence, I was wondering if I could generate this navigation mesh on the fly (from the list of cell, which is the newly generated path) and assign it to my steering actuator. Because the grid has been used as a graph for A* path finding and I could only get a list of cells as the path.

Comment: Wait... Is your problem about steering an object? I thought you meant that you want to create the physical mesh. If you don't need the object, you can simply have a loop in the Python that changes the objects position. What is the problem then? The pathtracing? Or did I once again get it wrong? Sorry if I am too dumb to understand.

Comment: Sorry, now I think I kinda got it. You have the path, but the steering actuator refuses to co-operate. My idea would be to have the position of the mesh modified inside the bge. (Loop over the cells and do an interpolation through another loop inside the outer one.) Any reason this is not applicable?

Comment: Thank you for your constant support. The second part is some what in the direction. I have the path but that is just the list of cells. To make the object move in the Game - Logic, I need to have a navigation mesh. My problem is to create this navigation mesh. This navigation mesh is such that, it very likely should have small planes like in the grid and these planes have the same center as the center of the cells which i have in the list.